# Is EPP really an Internet Protocol?

Tags: web-services, networking

I'm no expert but it seems to me that `EPP` and `SOAP` are web services that are transported on application layer protocols such as `HTTP` and `SMTP`.

So why are they deemed protocols?

Answer (score 0):

According to [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Communications_protocol):

> Within computer science, a communications protocol is a system of
>   digital rules for message exchange within or between computers.

And that's what exactly what EPP and SOAP does, so it's a protocol.

Protocols are typically layered on top of each other, as in the [OSI model](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Osi_model), though few real networks follow the OSI model exactly. SOAP is one such protocol, often transported on top of HTTP, (or in some cases JMS), defining rules and conventions about how you go about communicating.

Comment: Doesn't answer the question. OP asked whether it is an *Internet* protocol.

Comment: If the question is the subject, instead of the question in the body, the OP should clarify what he means by "internet protocols". It either refers specificially to IPv4 or IPv6, or to the protocols specified in a standards track RFC. Or the more informal use which may be "any protocol that can be run over the internet". SOAP is not an RFC, so in that regard it may not be an "internet protocol"

Comment: Question is, though, what is an _internet protocol_? If that's to signify one of the protocols in the internet protocol suite's application layer, the answer is clearly "no" (it's however layered on top of one of these), but otherwise I don't see how this answer is bad. "Between computers" can as well mean "over the internet", so it's sufficiently explained.